# Thompson's constuctor algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, automata, nfa

I'm trying to write regular expression parser

I'm using Thompson's contruction algorithm to convert Postfix to NFA

Problem is;

According to the output table, just one state has transitions but it is wrong. I made mistake somewhere in code but I can't find the broken part.

NFA.h :

```
#ifndef RE_FA_NFA_H
#define RE_FA_NFA_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include "Properties.h"

class NFA {
public:
    NFA(std::string& rgx);
    ~NFA();

private:
    typedef std::vector<std::vector <std::vector <int>>> t_Table;

    struct state_{
        bool finalState, isExist=false;
        int stateId;
        std::vector <state_> transitions;
        std::vector <state_> epsilonTransitions;
    };

    struct nfa_{
        state_ start;
        state_ end;
    };

    std::string postfix_;
    nfa_ currentNFA_;
    int stateCount;
    t_Table transitionTable_;

private:
    nfa_ postfix2nfa(std::string pfx);

    state_ createState(bool isFinal);
    void addTransition(state_& from, state_& to, char symbol);
    nfa_ fromEpsilon();
    nfa_ fromSymbol(char symbol);
    nfa_ star_(nfa_ nf);
    nfa_ concat_(nfa_ first, nfa_ second);
    nfa_ union_(nfa_& first, nfa_& second);

    void walk(const state_& walkingState, t_Table& table, std::vector <int>& visited);
    t_Table initTable();
    t_Table createTransitionTable();

public:
    nfa_ currentNfa();
    t_Table translationTable();

};


#endif //RE_FA_NFA_H
```

NFA.cpp :

```
#include "../include/NFA.h"


NFA::NFA(std::string& rgx) {
    stateCount = 0;
    postfix_ = rgx;
    currentNFA_ = postfix2nfa(postfix_);
    transitionTable_ = createTransitionTable();
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::postfix2nfa(std::string pfx) {
    if (pfx.empty()) {
        return fromEpsilon();
    }

    std::stack<nfa_> st;
    /** AAB|*.B. */
    for (char currentChar : pfx) {
        if (currentChar == STAR_SYMBOL) {
            nfa_ t = st.top();
            st.pop();
            st.push(star_(t));
        } else if (currentChar == CONCAT_SYMBOL) {
            nfa_ fist = st.top();
            st.pop();
            nfa_ second = st.top();
            st.pop();
            st.push(concat_(fist, second));
        } else if (currentChar == UNION_SYMBOL) {
            nfa_ first = st.top();
            st.pop();
            nfa_ second = st.top();
            st.pop();
            st.push(union_(first, second));
        } else {
            st.push(fromSymbol(currentChar));
        }
    }

    return st.top();
}

void NFA::addTransition(NFA::state_& from, NFA::state_& to, char symbol) {
    if (symbol == EPSILON_SYMBOL) {
        from.epsilonTransitions.push_back(to);
    } else {
        from.transitions[symbol - 'A'] = to;
    }
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::fromEpsilon() {
    nfa_ tmp;
    state_ start = createState(false);
    state_ end = createState(true);
    addTransition(start, end, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    tmp.start = start;
    tmp.end = end;
    return tmp;
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::fromSymbol(char symbol) {
    nfa_ tmp;
    state_ start = createState(false);
    state_ end = createState(true);
    addTransition(start, end, symbol);
    tmp.start = start;
    tmp.end = end;
    return tmp;
}

NFA::state_ NFA::createState(bool isFinal) {
    state_ newState, tempState;
    newState.finalState = isFinal;
    newState.transitions.resize(ALPHABET_SIZE);
    newState.isExist = true;
    newState.stateId = stateCount++;
    return newState;
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::star_(NFA::nfa_ currentNfa) {
    nfa_ tmp;
    state_ start = createState(false);
    state_ end = createState(true);

    addTransition(start, end, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    addTransition(start, currentNfa.start, EPSILON_SYMBOL);

    addTransition(currentNfa.end, end, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    addTransition(currentNfa.end, currentNfa.start, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    currentNfa.end.finalState = false;

    tmp.start = start;
    tmp.end = end;
    return tmp;
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::concat_(NFA::nfa_ first, NFA::nfa_ second) {
    nfa_ newNfa;
    addTransition(first.end, second.start, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    first.end.finalState = false;
    newNfa.start = first.start;
    newNfa.end = second.end;
    return newNfa;
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::union_(NFA::nfa_& first, NFA::nfa_& second) {
    nfa_ newNfa;

    state_ start = createState(false);
    state_ end = createState(true);

    addTransition(start, first.start, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    addTransition(start, second.start, EPSILON_SYMBOL);

    addTransition(first.end, end, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    first.end.finalState = false;
    addTransition(second.end, end, EPSILON_SYMBOL);
    second.end.finalState = false;

    newNfa.start = start;
    newNfa.end = end;
    return newNfa;
}

NFA::nfa_ NFA::currentNfa() {
    return currentNFA_;
}

NFA::t_Table NFA::translationTable() { return transitionTable_; }

NFA::t_Table NFA::createTransitionTable() {
    t_Table tb = initTable();
    std::vector <int> visited;
    walk(currentNFA_.start, tb, visited);
    return tb;
}

void NFA::walk(const NFA::state_& walkingState, t_Table& tb, std::vector<int>& visited) {
    int curId = walkingState.stateId;
    if (std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), curId) != visited.end()) return;


    for (const auto & nextState : walkingState.epsilonTransitions) {
        if (nextState.isExist){
            tb[curId][EPSILON_TRANSITIONS].push_back(nextState.stateId);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < walkingState.transitions.size(); ++k){
        std::cout << "\nk is" << k;
        if (walkingState.transitions[k].isExist){
            std::cout << "\nLOOONoliyy\n";
            tb[curId][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS][k] = walkingState.transitions[k].stateId;
        }
    }

    visited.push_back(walkingState.stateId);


    int targetId;
    for (int i = 0; i < tb[curId][EPSILON_TRANSITIONS].size(); ++i) {
        targetId = tb[curId][EPSILON_TRANSITIONS][i];
        for (const auto & nextState : walkingState.epsilonTransitions) {
            if (nextState.isExist){
                if (nextState.stateId == targetId){
                    walk(nextState, tb, visited);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < tb[curId][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS].size(); ++j) {
        if (tb[curId][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS][j] != UNUSED_TRANSITION){
            targetId = tb[curId][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS][j];
            for (const auto & nextState : walkingState.transitions) {
                if (nextState.isExist){
                    if (nextState.stateId == targetId){
                        walk(nextState, tb, visited);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

NFA::t_Table NFA::initTable() {
    t_Table newTable;
    newTable.resize(stateCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < stateCount; ++i) {
        newTable[i].resize(COLUMN_COUNT);
        newTable[i][STATE_ID] = {i};
        newTable[i][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS].assign(ALPHABET_SIZE, -1);
    }

    return newTable;
}

NFA::~NFA() = default;
```

Properties.h :

```
#ifndef RE_FA_PROPERTIES_H
#define RE_FA_PROPERTIES_H

/** MODE **/
#define DEBUG true
#define INFO false

/** SYMBOLS **/
#define STAR_SYMBOL '*'
#define OPEN_PARENTHESIS_SYMBOL '('
#define CLOSE_PARENTHESIS_SYMBOL ')'
#define UNION_SYMBOL '|'
#define CONCAT_SYMBOL '.'
#define EPSILON_SYMBOL 26


#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26  // Alphabet [A-Z]

/** PRIORITIES **/
#define STAR_PRIORITY 3
#define CONCAT_PRIORITY 2
#define UNION_PRIORITY 1
#define MIN_PRIORITY 0

/** TRANSLATION TABLE **/
#define STATE_ID 0
#define EPSILON_TRANSITIONS 1
#define SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS 2

#define COLUMN_COUNT 3
#define UNUSED_TRANSITION -1

#endif //RE_FA_PROPERTIES_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "include/Properties.h"
#include "include/NFA.h"

int main(){
    NFA nfa(std::string("AAB|*.B."));
    std::vector<std::vector <std::vector <int>>> table = nfa.translationTable();

    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < table.size(); ++row) {
        std::cout << table[row][STATE_ID].back();
        std::cout << "\t-->\t\t";
        for (int i = 0; i < table[row][EPSILON_TRANSITIONS].size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << table[row][EPSILON_TRANSITIONS][i] << "(€), ";
        }
        std::cout << " | ";
        for (int j = 0; j < table[row][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS].size(); ++j) {
            std::cout << table[row][SYMBOL_TRANSITIONS][j] << "\t|\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input postfix example : `AAB|*.B.`

Comment: did you try stepping through with your debugger?

Comment: Since we're living in the year 2020 why not use `auto` more rather than repeat verbose definitions? Or at least use some `typedef` declarations to tidy that up.

Comment: @tadman It makes sense, thanks. I will be considering your suggestion, I'm just learning c ++.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning. I wish I could help more but there's a *lot* of code here to review and it's really complicated by how much apparent duplication there is in it. For example, instead of using a variable like `i` to iterate over a `vector`, instead you can do `for (auto& v : vector)` and then just work with the value `v`. This is *way* less code. If you apply this at each level you massively reduce how much code you have, like `table[row]` becomes `row`, etc.

Comment: Also, remove all the `#define`s. You can replace them with `constexpr char`s.

Comment: @cigien thanks, I will be considering that too.

Comment: It's also strange that you're returning a `std::vector` instead of having accessors to the internal contents. Ideally you could have an interface like `for (auto& row : table.epsilonTransitions())` and be done with it. Since you have a proper C++ class, make it more useful to the caller. Don't be so protective about things. Expose `const` references where appropriate.

Comment: @tadman It is awesome, I will try to do it from now on

Comment: I think some of the issues here might have to do with the fact that each state represents its transitions and epsilon transitions as a list of concrete `state` objects rather than *pointers* to state objects. This means that mutually referencing states will each store *copies* of the states they reference rather than simply saying "oh, I'm referencing that state over there."

Comment: A separate note - you've posted an enormous amount of code here and just a single test case where things fail. I think you'll need to break this question down into smaller pieces to make it more managable. For example, are you 100% sure, beyond a reasonable doubt, that the parser works? If so, what test cases have you run in isolation to confirm this? Next, are you 100% sure that each of the constructions applied work correctly? If so, what test cases have you run in isolation to confirm this?